# remove .svn while building debian packages

Tags: svn, debian, apt, package-managers, debhelper

While building a Debian package we use a debian/mypackagename.install file to tell debhelper packaging tool where to copy files and folder.

The problem is that folders contain a .svn folder which is copied in to package tree and finally goes to target machine! is there a standard way to exclude .svn folders while package building?

Comment: I don't know about debian and packaging, but you could use svn export to export the working copy (excluding the .svn files), and then package the exported directory.

Comment: thanks, you are right, using svn export is the standard way i have forgotten about it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a bash script to remove all .svn folders from the project folder and sub-folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your build system looks in details but to exclude .svn (CVS, .git, etc.) you can use `-X` option of `dh_install`:

```
$ dh_install -X .svn
```

or export DH_ALWAYS_EXCLUDE variable in `debian/rules` file:

```
$ cat debian/rules 
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
# As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
# dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
# This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
# export DH_VERBOSE=1

export DH_ALWAYS_EXCLUDE=CVS:.svn

%:
    dh  $@
```

Comment: Additionally `$ debuild -I` will ignore VCS directories when building .tar.gz with your sources. This `-I` option is not mentioned in man, but you'll find it in the sources of debuild.

Comment: I checked and the `debuild -I` also works for `.git` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As  @JB_Nizet correct wrote you can use `svn export` to get directory without all the .svn folders. If you can't use export, you can use `find -name .svn -and -type d -exec rm -rf {} +` to delete all .svn folders in a directory recursively.